# Fast way to generate samples with np.random.choice()?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to generate random sample without replacement for `N` times, like following:

```py
import numpy as np

sample = np.zeros([100000, 4], int)
for i in range(100000):
    sample[i] = np.random.choice(128, 4, replace=False)
```

If the iterations become very large, the overall sampling will be time consuming. Is there any way to speed up this sampling?

Comment: Lock at this article: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-embarrassingly-fast-random-subset-sampling-with-python-da9b27d494d9

Comment: so, you want 2D array , one of its dimensions is large while the other is small

Comment: So you want to sample without replacement in one dimension, but with replacement in the other (or to do that sample repeatedly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method

```
In [16]: sample = np.zeros([100000, 4], int)

In [17]: %timeit for i in range(100000):sample[i] = np.random.choice(128, 4, rep
    ...: lace=False)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.5 s per loop
```

While you can write:

```
In [149]: %timeit d=np.random.choice(128,100000);sample1=np.array([(d+x)%128 for x in np.random.choice(128,4)])
The slowest run took 4.63 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 4.11 ms per loop
```

**This is way faster on my machine**

This is less random maybe, but this depends on your application.
after all `for` loop is very slow in vanilla python. you maybe interested in [Cython](https://cython.org/), or [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a random int range(0,128) in the shape (100000,4)

```
np.random.randint(128, size=(100000,4))
```

Comment: This won't guarantee sampling without replacement though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.sample` instead of `np.random.choice`

```
In [16]: import time
    ...: start_time = time.time()
    ...: sample = np.zeros([100000, 4], int)
    ...: for i in range(100000):
    ...:     sample[i] = random.sample(range(128), 4)
    ...: print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    ...: 
--- 0.7096474170684814 seconds ---

In [17]: import time
    ...: start_time = time.time()
    ...: sample = np.zeros([100000, 4], int)
    ...: for i in range(100000):
    ...:     sample[i] = np.random.choice(128, 4, replace=False)
    ...: print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    ...: 
--- 5.2036824226379395 seconds ---
```

Comment: Oh man. Use `timeit` for timing runtime, but `np.random.choice` is not meant to be called in a loop - you can pass a `shape` to it and call it once. This timing doesn't really make much sense. Anything can affect your timings if you run it once